# Animating a list-item to a negative top makes other list-items goes down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I'm trying to apply an effect with `jQuery.animate()` to a list-item on `mouseenter`, changing `top` property to a negative value and also changing `height`, but while the animation is being done, a glitch occurs in the other elements in my list. It stops when the animation is complete.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ravan/rPL66/) that shows the glitch.

Notice that if the css is applied without any animation, it works as expected. Here's another [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ravan/NGcyk/).

I'm missing something? Is there a way to achieve this effect properly?

Comment: works perfectly in my browser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because animate includes an `overflow: hidden` inline style while animating. Insert `overflow: visible !important;` to your style for the list items and it works fine for me (tested in firefox only)